# Deploy DRF on azure using GitHub Actions

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I developed a simple DRF application that uses git hub actions to deploy the app to azure web services.
I configured the yaml file to take the database connection string from git hub secrets.(one step in the yaml file is to run migrations) -  this performs ok.
After build and deploy, when i try to run the app(navigate to the specific url) i get and application error. Looking over the logs, i noticed this error

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DATABASE_URL environment variable

Now, i know what the problem means, but how can i override the connection string from the environ.py file.

The yaml file

```
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: djangotutorial2    # set this to the name of your Azure Web App
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.11.6'              # set this to the Python version to use
  DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.DATABASE_URL }}

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3.0.0
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}
          cache: 'pip'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python3 -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
          
      - name: Upgrade pip
        run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
      
      - name: install python-xlib
        run: pip install python-xlib

      - name: apply migrations
        run: python3 manage.py migrate

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            .
            !venv/

  deploy:
    permissions:
      contents: none
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Development'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
```

I tried to put the database_url in the environmental  variables in git hub but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your YAML file, you are setting `DATABASE_URL` as an environment variable at the job level.
But I fail to see how that would be passed to the [Azure Web App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/app-service/web/).
Remove the `DATABASE_URL` line from the `env` section in your YAML file: it should be set in the Azure configuration.

Go to your Azure Web App in the Azure portal. Navigate to the "Configuration" section (see "[Configure an App Service app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-app-settings)"). Add a new application setting with the name `DATABASE_URL` and the value you have in your GitHub Secrets.
Make sure your Django settings are configured to use the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you. That is how i did and it worked. I forgot about this due to lack of exp.

Comment: @RaduAlexandru no problem, well done.